# Как лучше всего генерировать номера заказа для Интернет-магазина?

Tags: php, архитектура, структуры, структуры-данных

Есть в таблице Order поле number, который содержит номер заказа для Интернет-магазина. Каким способом его генерировать лучше всего?

ID не подходит, так как считаю что его лучше спрятать от посторонних глаз. Auto increment уже назначен на поле ID.

Приходил к мнению генерации UNIX Time и разбить время на формат 9999-9999-9999. Но пришёл к выводу, что это очень длинный и не удобный номер заказа. Хотелось бы сократить до 6-7 знаков и только числами.

Моя конструкция:

```
$orderNumber = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

UPDATE.

Повторюсь, главный вопрос: "как лучше всего генерировать номера заказа", а не как id повлияет на безопасность.

Comment: Чего именно вы опасаетесь? Какие риски несет в себе назначение номера заказа из ряда идущих подряд чисел?

Comment: @tutankhamun не знаю, но главное не в безопасности конечно, хотя тоже не маловажно. Глядя на пример крупных интернет магазинов, можно заметить что номера заказа там не ID аля 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 и т. д. Номера заказа там можно встретить даже с буквой аля XY-15. Хочется делать также как это делают остальные. Но вот главный вопрос, по какому принципу генерировать такие номера.

Comment: @vladiik, это известный вопрос шашечек и езды. Вам нужно скопировать модель поведения другого ПО или написать свое? Обычно дополнительные части номера заказа указывают на конкретные вещи, например, номер склада, точку заказа, посредника, или еще что-то, пока у вас этого нет, вы можете об этом не беспокоиться.

Comment: У нас есть и склады и посредники и курьеры. Хочется найти какое то хорошее решение в этом вопросе. Меня не интересует непосредственно реализация программно. Меня интересует само формирование, его образование.

Comment: В генерации можно как угодно изгаляться, главное, чтобы было unique. А там хоть bin2hex(random_bytes(10)) с конкатенацией юникстайма, хоть rand, хоть sha/md5 от автоинкрементного поля, тут руки развязаны. Так же не вижу проблем с секурностью, если это будет просто id из базы, но если кто-то подскажет вектор атаки, буду крайне признателен.

Answer (score 1):

автоинкремент. пример кода:

```
$id = $db->insertId();
```

Comment: вы используете id в качестве номера заказа? Разве это безопасно?

Comment: @vladiik это к вам вопрос. Искажать их -- не более чем "безопасность через неясность". Вы можете сходу подобрать вектор атаки?

Comment: @D-side Насколько я знаю, все известные интернет магазины используют отдельное поле для хранения номера заказа (Sylius, Magento например). Собственно главный вопрос не в этом. Есть что по сабжу ответить?

Comment: @vladiik поясню предыдущий комментарий: в зависимости от архитектуры это **может** быть безопасно: например, если на сайте нет общедоступного запроса заказа по его id. Этого можно добиться, выдавая детали заказа только при его создании (ответ на POST) или на почту.

Comment: Меня интересует не безопасность. А сама генерация, её образование. По какому принципу формируется номер заказа.

Comment: @vladiik в первом комментарии вас интересовала именно безопасность :)